# Additional row on end when last row has [wartosc] = 1 or on top when first row when [wartosc] = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table (in SQL Server) with process data containing nazwa, wartosc, jakosc, czas.

I add rows when value is changing. Always I have [wartosc] = 1 or 0.

Then I show all records between two datetime.

```
start time = '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000'
end time = '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
```

The table data look something like this:

[image]

I wrote query:

```
;WITH [cteRows] AS
(
    SELECT  [nazwa],
            [wartosc],
            [czas],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas]) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7]
    WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' 
    AND [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' 
    AND [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
)

,cteNewRows AS
(
    SELECT  mc.[RowNumber],
            mc.[czas],
            mc.[nazwa],
            mc.[wartosc],
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.[czas], ISNULL(mp.[czas], mc.[czas])) AS [Wsekundach]
    FROM [cteRows] mc 
    LEFT JOIN [cteRows] mp  ON mc.[RowNumber] = mp.[RowNumber] + 1 
    WHERE mc.[wartosc] = 0 
)

SELECT  SUM(Wsekundach) AS SumOfWsekundach
FROM    cteNewRows
```

Now I am summing time (SumOfWsekundach, how long "1" was and I have a little error, but I check only rows when [wartosc] = 0 and I subtract two rows.

When first row has [wartosc] = 0, this means that earlier was "1" and i must add this time between (starttime and time first row). Also it is when last row has [wartosc] = 1, it's mean that I must also add time (endtime - time last row)

How can I do it?

I would like to have, how long was Hydraulic on, so I must have time, how long "1" was between two datetime from start time to end time.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you shouldn't use Polish in code/database ;)

Comment: or any other non-English language, for that matter.